# Does "complement the deficiencies" make sense?

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage

I would like to construct this sentence: "Our strengths complement each others' deficiencies".

Does that make sense?

Comment: "make up for" would be better.

Comment: better or more correct?

Comment: I'm unsure. It's the wrong end of the day. You sentence makes sense to me.

Comment: But I think your suggestion is better.

Comment: @JessicaCage It may be possible to go with your sentence if we knew something of the context.

Comment: A definition of 'complement' (v) is needed. But you may thinking of 'compensate for', which, like Mick's synonymous suggestion, is correct.

Comment: "Compensate for" would be a better choice.

Comment: Or offset each others' deficiencies. Make up for would also work per @Mick's comment.

Comment: I think you should pair 'weaknesses' with 'strengths', rather than 'deficiencies'.

Comment: Ya. Even I suppose 'make up ' fits here. Complement as a verb , is defined by Google as "a thing that contributes extra features to something else in such a way as to improve or emphasize its quality.
"local ales provide the perfect complement to fine food" " which definitely doesn't fit the context of the sentence mentioned. The strengths don't add anything to the existing deficiencies. They make those up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned, I would go with *compensate for* or *make up for*.

As you can see from the definition below, *complementing* something means that it 'goes well with it'.

> something that completes something else or makes it better

([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/complement))

Alternatively, you might want *compensate*:

> to provide something good as a balance against something bad or undesirable : *to make up for some defect or weakness*

([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compensate))

This seems to almost exactly match your description of the word.